# Accessing external resources with phonegap

Tags: jquery, xml, cordova

I tested an app I built locally with dreamweaver jQuery mobile is able to access external resources from the server.after compiling my app with dreamweaver phonegap, I've discovered that my app cannot connect  remotely to access the external resources . i used eclipse and i was able to point out the starting point for my app using `super.loadUrl("http://webaddress/folder/index.html");`. is there any way i can point out a starting point for my app using my config.xml for dreamweaver phonegap.

```
<?xml version="1.3.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.3.1"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    version   = "1.3.1.0">

<name>Go tv app</name>

<description>
A simple PhoneGap Build application.
</description>

<author href="https://example.com" email="you@example.com">
Benjamin Blay
</author>

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.3.1/device" />

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.0.0" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />

 <!-- Icons -->

   <icon src="icon.png" />
   <icon src="images/icon-72x72.png" width="72" height="72" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
   <icon src="images/icon-96x96.png" width="96" height="96" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
   <icon src="images/icon-72x72.png" width="72" height="72" gap:platform="ios" />

  <!-- Splash Screens -->
   <gap:splash src="splash_screen.jpg" />
   <gap:splash src="images/splash_screen-160x220.jpg" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
   <gap:splash src="splash_screen.jpg" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
   <gap:splash src="images/splash_screen-450x650.jpg" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />



</widget>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to access external resources in Phonegap v3.1:
Open your config.xml file, change:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
```

to

```
<access origin="*" />
```

The * is used as a wildcard to indicate that any value may go there, so `<access origin="*"/>` indicates that the app is allowed to access any resouce on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

add `<access origin=".*"/>`to your confog.xml , please use latest phonegap version

```
  <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

<!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
<!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
<access origin=".*"/>
```

Comment: please should i replace the ip address with my server address? example<access origin="http://myaddress.com*"/>

Comment: @Arjun it is possible to use both?